# Alignment issue in the site's "contact us" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, help-center, contact

In the [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) page, the **Search the Help Center** is aligned to the bottom.

Previously it was aligned properly, I can see in the [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20170202131736/https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

This alignment issue is in the all site's contact us page and in the Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Search help center in bottom]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was completed a while back, sorry that we didn't respond to this individually. That this was broken was a bit of a fluke that was caused by something else that was pretty temporary in nature; I'm digging through these (and quite a few other glitch related things) to make sure they get updated.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just for getting hats? ....

Comment: Yep. I'd have just left a comment and an upvote if there was an answer to this :)